# Strong Params: params.permit returns Unpermitted parameters despite whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

UsersProfileController has strong params that looks like so:

```
    def user_profile_params
      params.permit(:age, :relations)
      # yes, I am not requiring user_profile. Just permitting attributes I need. 
    end
```

The create action builds UserProfile through a parent (has-one and belongs-to association)

```
    def create
      parent = Parent.create_guest
      parent.build_user_profile(user_profile_params)
      if parent.save 
        # do something 
      else 
        # handle error
      end
    end
```

Calling params in UserProfiles returns:

```
    <ActionController::Parameters 
      {"age"=>"23", 
       "relations"=>"3", 
       "subdomain"=>"api", 
       "format"=>:json, 
       "controller"=>"api/v1/user_profiles", 
       "action"=>"create"} 
     permitted: false>
```

Calling user_profile_params, returns this:

```
    user_profile_params:
      Unpermitted parameters: subdomain, format
      <ActionController::Parameters 
       {"age"=>"23", 
       "relations"=>"3", } 
      permitted: true>
```

When a post request comes in, I expect to be able to create user_profile using the whitelisted params in user_profile_params. Instead, the `create` action in UserProfiles fails with error: `Unpermitted parameters: subdomain, format`.

This isn't what I expected. I expected user_profile_params to only include the permitted values and ignore all others.

I could add `:format` and `:subdomain` to list of permitted attributes but something feels a bit off about that.

Can someone explain what is going on/what I am missing?

Comment: It appears to me that you are not actually passing through that create block in your UsersProfileController.

Comment: @ChrisMoody: Not sure I understand what you mean.  If you mean the method doesn't get called, then that isn't true. Was able to step into the `create` action in the UsersProfileController and found that error occurs when `user_profile_params` is called on this specific line `parent.build_user_profile(user_profile_params)`.  Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message is just a **warning**, and not an **error/exception**. If your model it's not being persisted, that's by another reason.

From the [strong parameters docs](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

> **Handling of Unpermitted Keys**
>
> By default parameter keys that are not explicitly permitted will be
>   logged in the development and test environment. In other environments
>   these parameters will simply be filtered out and ignored.
>
> Additionally, this behaviour can be changed by changing the
>   config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters property in
>   your environment files. If set to :log the unpermitted attributes will
>   be logged, if set to :raise an exception will be raised.

You can simulate it in your console (`rails c`):

```
fake_params_hash = {
    "age"=>"23", 
    "relations"=>"3", 
    "subdomain"=>"api", 
    "format"=>:json, 
    "controller"=>"api/v1/user_profiles", 
    "action"=>"create"
} 

permited_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(fake_params_hash).permit(:age, :relations)
#=> Unpermitted parameters: subdomain, format <== warning logged to the console
#=> <ActionController::Parameters {"age"=>"23", "relations"=>"3"} permitted: true>


user = User.create(permited_params) #mass assigment with permited params

#check if there are errors
puts user.errors.messages if user.errors.any?
```

As you can see, this message is not thrown by the `User.create`, but when `.permit` is invoked.

Comment: You are correct. Was actually coming to post that the error was due to validation on `User` model. Thanks for taking time out to answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @mrlew's answer, if we have an array, we need to permit the parameters inside the array. Otherwise, the warning message will keep showing.

```rb
fake_params_hash = {
    "age"=>"23",
    "relations"=>"3",
    "subdomain"=>"api",
    "format"=>:json,
    "array"=>[
        "sub_item"=>"hello"
    ],
    "controller"=>"api/v1/user_profiles",
    "action"=>"create"
}

permited_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(fake_params_hash).permit(:age, :relations, :array)

#=> Unpermitted parameters: :subdomain, :format, :array

permited_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(fake_params_hash).permit(:age, :relations, array: [:sub_item])

#=> Unpermitted parameters: :subdomain, :format
```

It took me half a day to realise this in order to solve a bug at work...